# How do I enable my Bluetooth adapter on Dell Inspiron N4030?

Tags: bluetooth, dell

I'm using Dell Inspiron N4030 laptop. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

Bluetooth adapter is not found. How to active that?

```
rfkill list
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Not sure but, I enable it using `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`

Comment: Broadcom bluetooth on linux is a very complex issue. It is possible to solve, but it is not a matter of "answers". Try ubuntuforums.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the hardware switch is on.

To activate your Bluetooth, you will need to hold down the <kbd>FN</kbd> key, and then tap the <kbd>F2</kbd> key once. This should activate the Bluetooth.

Also, Press the <kbd>F2</kbd> key when you power on the system. This should take you to the Bios Screen. Under the Advanced Tab select wireless, and make sure that the bluetooth is set to enabled.

Comment: Everything is fine. But its not working. In windows bluetooth is working. Any other suggestions?